# How to start iOS programming in 2013?

Tags: iphone, ios

I just finished reading Apple's official guide [Programming with Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html).
Then I try to find some other books to continue learning. Sadly, almost all the books are out of date...
So what's next?

Comment: *Who is upvoting non constructing question?* :/

Comment: I am upvoting and I don't agree this question is non-constructive.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly advise taking the [CS193P Stanford Course](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/). About 5 months ago, I went through the whole thing. I just got down the very last concept of the course 5 minutes ago (lol). And I feel like I very thoroughly understand programming for both iOS and iPad.

Comment: There's a new course coming out for iOS 6. I think it comes out by the 22nd: http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with every new version of ios Apple made there are always updates are changes. SO, we have to keep updated with this. You can find [here](http://www.apress.com/9781430245124) a good book to start with IOS 6. it's written by the team of the best selling  : Beginning iPhone Development.